# Concatenate gzipped CSVs into one escaping headers

Tags: bash, shell

There are a few thousands of `gzip`ped `csv` files in the folder. 
Each of the compressed csv files has a header.

How do i concatenate all those `gzip`ped  csv files into one csv file while escaping all the header rows?

EDIT: Headers are identical. Order of the files doesn't matter.

Comment: Are all the headers identical? Does the order of the files matter? What did you try and in what way was the result not what you wanted?

Comment: @rici updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in *.gz; do zcat "$i" | sed -n '2,$p'; done > output.csv
```

or

```
for i in *.gz; do zcat "$i" | sed '1d'; done > output.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where/how do i specify the output file name?

Comment: And what is the difference between those two?

Comment: Same result. The second one is shorter.

Comment: Another short question. Isn't > supposed to override file?  Shouldn't >> be used? Your solution works, but i'm trying to understand the details.

Comment: This redirect is performed only once. `> output.csv` after `done` redirects all stdout from inside the `for` loop to file output.csv. If you place the redirect in the loop you need `>>` because this redirect is performed multiple times: `zcat "$i" | sed '1d' >> output.csv`